# Statistical Test for Evolution of a Population Proportion?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, population

The problem I am faced with is as follows - there is some population proportion $p$ of people with a certain characteristic that is evolving over time. We take new samples every day (without replacement). Is there a statistical test that will allow us to deduce precisely when this population proportion changed?

I tried conducting a chi-squared test by comparing all of the testing data before a certain day to all of the data after a certain day, but this returned a result that confirmed a change in $p$ for every single day. I could also do a chi-squared test up till a certain day, as compared to on the next day. Lastly, I could do a chi-squared test from yesterday to today.

They yield different results, with different conclusions. Which is most appropriate, and is there a better way?

Comment: You are looking for a changepoint test, possibly for the binomial proportion parameter. Using those keywords might net you more results.

Comment: Could you say more about the kind of change you're looking for? "Evolving over time" suggests the proportion could vary continuously from day to day. But "deducing precisely when this proportion changed" sounds like the proportion might be constant for a period of time, then switch to a new constant value (as in change point models). Since it sounds like you're looking for a significance test, what's your null hypothesis?